# Sort Multi Dimensional Array efficiently

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

Here is the content of my array:

```
array(
  'June 01, 2014' => array(
    (int) 722107 => array(
        'date' => 'June 01, 2014',
        'start_time' => '2:00 AM',
        'end_time' => '03:00 AM'
    ),
    (int) 117646 => array(
        'date' => 'June 01, 2014',
        'start_time' => '12:30 AM',
        'end_time' => '03:30 AM'
    )
  ),
  'May 31, 2014' => array(
    (int) 769349 => array(
        'date' => 'May 31, 2014',
        'start_time' => '12:30 AM',
        'end_time' => '03:30 AM'
    )
  )
)
```

And the output I want is it should sorted first by keys (Date in ASC), then sort again the values of each keys by the start time in ASC.

Based on the example above it should output:

```
array(
     'May 31, 2014' => array(
    (int) 769349 => array(
        'date' => 'May 31, 2014',
        'start_time' => '12:30 AM',
        'end_time' => '03:30 AM'
    )
 ),
'June 01, 2014' => array(

    (int) 117646 => array(
        'date' => 'June 01, 2014',
        'start_time' => '12:30 AM',
        'end_time' => '03:30 AM'
    ),
    (int) 722107 => array(
        'date' => 'June 01, 2014',
        'start_time' => '2:00 AM',
        'end_time' => '03:00 AM'
    )
   )

    )
```

Comment: So you want to sort it by the date?

Comment: @Darren Yes the date the first keys, then once it is sorted by keys. Sort again the values of each keys base on start_time so everything will  be in order.

Comment: Is this coming from a database? If so, easy enough to sort it in your find query

Comment: @scrowler, its not coming from a database, its easier that way, but its from a session variable.

Comment: Is this the result of some sort of SQL query? I understand that you are looking for a PHP solution, but maybe you overlooked something, like sorting in the SQL query itself. Again: I don't know if it is of any concern here, but I'm just thinking with you ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two passes can be with `uksort()` and `uasort()` using a custom function to compare two dates:

```
function timeCompare($a, $b)
{
    $va = strtotime($a);
    $vb = strtotime($b);

    if ($va != $vb) {
        return $va < $vb ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

// first pass (sort outer elements)
uksort($data, 'timeCompare');
// second pass (sort inner elements)
foreach ($data as &$item) {
    uasort($item, function($a, $b) {
        return timeCompare($a['start_time'], $b['start_time']);
    });
}
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GYXpUI)

Comment: @zynder I've tested it with your given input and it produces the correct output with that; please give counter example (also, check the added demo).

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry about that Jack. Thank you to the both of you Jack and @darren.

Answer (score 2):

this will sort it the way you requested.

```
$sort = array();
foreach ($d as $key => $item) {
    $sort[$key] = strtotime($key);
}
array_multisort($sort, SORT_ASC, $d);

function sortme($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a['date']) - strtotime($b['date']);
}

foreach ($d as $k => $i) {
    usort($i, "sortme");
}
```

Which returns:

```
Array
(
    [May 31, 2014] => Array
        (
            [769349] => Array
                (
                    [date] => May 31, 2014
                    [start_time] => 12:30 AM
                    [end_time] => 03:30 AM
                )

        )

    [June 01, 2014] => Array
        (
            [722107] => Array
                (
                    [date] => June 01, 2014
                    [start_time] => 2:00 AM
                    [end_time] => 03:00 AM
                )

            [117646] => Array
                (
                    [date] => June 01, 2014
                    [start_time] => 12:30 AM
                    [end_time] => 03:30 AM
                )

        )

)
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/166926)

---

### Explanation

- Basically the first function will sort the dates `May 31, 2014/ June 01, 2014/ ETC`.
- The second step is the `foreach` loop with goes through the child arrays to sort them my the date/time.
- Voila, sorted array :-)

Comment: @zynder Sorry yes `$d` is the data parsed through (The original array)

Comment: Also on that part on the key June 1, 2014, the child array first index must be the 117646 because its start time is 12:30am.